# Orthonormalization of basis ${1,1+t,2t^2}$ by $\langle u,v\rangle = \int_{0}^{1}uvdt$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Im doing the process:

$$g_1 = \frac{1}{||1||} = 1\\v_2 = 1+t-<1+t,1>1 = 1+t-\int_{0}^{1}(1+t)1dt = t-\frac{1}{2}\\g_2 = \frac{v_2}{||v_2||}$$

but $$||v_2|| = \int_{0}^{1}t-\frac{1}{2}dt = 0$$

:(

Comment: $$\|v_2\|^2=\int_{0}^{1}(t-1/2)^2\ \text dt\ ?$$

Comment: Are you aiming to perform orthogonalization by gram-schmidt or by what method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake in the line $||v_2||=\int_0^1t-\frac{1}{2}dt$

In fact, $||v_2||=\int_0^1v_2^2dt=\int_0^1(t-\frac{1}{2})^2dt$

your clue is when the norm of a non-zero element is zero